# How to access a linked list pointed to by a void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

[enter image description here][1]I just started leaning C++ and I have been given a course project.

> The initial data is located into a data structure consisting of arrays of pointers, headers and items

```cpp
typedef struct headerA
{
    void* pItems;  // Pointer to the linked list of items. 
                   // Items may be of types ITEM1...ITEM10.
    char cBegin;   // The linked list contains objects in which
                   // the first letter of the second word
                   // of ID cBegin.
    struct headerA* pNext;
} HEADER_A;

typedef struct item1
{
    char* pID;
    unsigned long int Code;
    char* pTime; // formatted as hh::mm::ss
    struct item1* pNext;
} ITEM1;
 
HEADER_A * *p = GetStruct3(3, 100);
ITEM1* pNewItem = (ITEM1*)GetItem(1); // generates a stand-alone item of type iItem and returns the 
//pointer to it.
int i = 0;
while (p[i] != NULL) // p is a an array of pointers to linked list of Headers
{
    pNew = p[i]->pNext; // accessing the first Header. Each header points to a 
    //linked list of Items
    while (pNew)   // looping through the linked list of each header
    {
        pNew->pItems = pNewItem; // This is where I have a problem. how to access 
      //the void * pItems

        while (pNewItem) // looping through the linked list of Items
        {
            cout << pNewItem->Code << pNewItem->pID << pNewItem->pTime << endl;
            pNewItem = pNewItem->pNext;
        }
        pNew = pNew->pNext;
    }
    i++;
}
```

My problem is, I am unable to properly access the linked list of Items in each Header.

```cpp
void* pItems;  // Pointer to the linked list of items.
```

When I used a typecast `pNewItem = (ITEM1*)pNew->pItems;`, it prints only the first item in the first header, and the `while` loops don't work anymore.

How do I access the linked list of `ITEM` in each header pointed to by a `void*` pointer, using C++ style?

```
 HEADER_A **p = GetStruct3(3, 100);
ITEM1* pNewItem = (ITEM1*)GetItem(1);
ITEM3* pNewItem2 = (ITEM3*)GetItem(3);
HEADER_A* pNew;
 int i = 0;
while (p[i] != NULL)
{  
    pNew = p[i]->pNext;
    cout << i << endl;
    while (pNew)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        cout << pNew->cBegin << endl;
        pNew->pItems = pNewItem;
        pNewItem12 = pNewItem;
        
        while (pNewItem12)
        {
            cout << pNewItem12->Code << pNewItem12->pID << pNewItem12->pTime 
   << endl;
            cout << " we are now here12" << endl;
            pNewItem12 = pNewItem12->pNext;   
        }
        cout << " we are now her1234e" << endl;
        pNew = pNew->pNext;
    }
    i++;
```

This is sample output from the code snippet above

```
0
0
T
1686042807Lime Green10:34:47
we are now here12
we are now her1234e
0
W
1686042807Lime Green10:34:47
we are now here12
we are now her1234e
1
1
G
1686042807Lime Green10:34:47
we are now here12
we are now her1234e
1
```

This is not the complete output but it shows that it is looping through the while loops but it is printing the same item that i generated in the beginning not the ones in the structure, This is because I am having difficulties going through the list of linked list of Item pointed to by void* pItem in each Header
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh3av.jpg

Comment: Add some code that shows the data you have put in the linked list.

Comment: @Tarik the function GetStruct3(3, 100) generates the data structure. My task is to print the data in the data structure or print an error message if it is empty

Comment: Is the code supposed to append the new item to the end of the item list or prepend it to the start of the item list? At the moment, it seems to be replacing the existing item list. Also, it looks like it is trying to add the same item to more than one list, which cannot work because the item only has a single link pointer.

Comment: @IanAbbott I am trying to print the data in the data structure that was generated

Comment: If the linked list items may be of different types, as the code comment suggests, then how do you know the type of each one?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes GetStruct3() returns an array of pointers. 
From the Header structure in the code, it shows that the linked list of Items is void *pItems. So my problem is how to print the list of Items of each header. When I typecast to ITEM1 data type, it prints just one Item. That is where i am facing difficulties

Comment: Since you seem to be using C++ (judging by the use of `cout`), conversions between `void *` and other pointer types need a cast operator, so `pNew = p[i]->pNext;` should be `pNew = (void *)p[i]->pNext;` (in C-style code) or the fancy C++ way of doing the same thing with `static_cast`.

Comment: @IanAbbott pNew is a pointer to  Header A data type and p[i]->pNext is a pointer to a Header A data type, so I guess I don't have to typecast. typecasting is needed at the level of pNew->pItems = pNewItem; but I don't know how it works because when I try typecasting, it prints just the first Item and does not loop again

Comment: @IanAbbott I also read somewhere that typecasting a void pointer is necessary to tell the compiler the amount of memory to dereference. this might not be the exact statement but it gives the general idea. So no that my void pointer points to a linked list, how do I typecast it?

Comment: Using for() loops instead of while() loops will save you at least 4 lines of code and reveal the error.

Comment: What does `GetItem(1)` actually do?

Comment: @IanAbbott  it generates a stand-alone item of type iItem1 and returns a 
pointer to it. When I use that pointer, it prints only the data in the Item1 throughout all the loops.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You were right about the unknown type of the Items in the linked list due to the fact that they are pointed to by a void pointer. When I used ITEM3, (there ten different ITEM types) I was able to print the the list of each item in each header, but with ITEM1 it is not working correctly. The problem was that the lecturer gave me a task with ITEM1. Thanks! first breakthrough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed my error. The datatype of the pointer I was typecasting to was not the same as the datatype of the Items in the linked list pointed to by the void pointer.